# Mysqli prepared statement image fetching error

Tags: php, mysql, hamming-distance

SImply,searching and fecthing image from path in mysqli like this working corectly:

```
<?php

$DBServer = 'localhost'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'root';
$DBPass   = '';
$DBName   = 'water';
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$image = $GET['image'];

$sql = " SELECT kiti FROM `database` WHERE value LIKE '%$image%' ";

if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']');
}
$file_path = 'photos/';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $src=$file_path.'/'.$row["key"];

     echo '<img class="myimg" src="'.$src.'" alt="There ya go" width="100" height="100" />';
   }

$conn->close();

  ?>
```

But due to sql injection fear,created it like prepared statement,but it's not fetching images,pls help:

```
<?php

$DBServer = 'localhost'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'root';
$DBPass   = '';
$DBName   = 'water';
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$image = $GET['image'];

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT kiti FROM `database` WHERE value=?")) {

    // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $image);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($key);
   // Fetch the data.
    $stmt->fetch();

   $result = $stmt->get_result();

   $file_path = 'photos/';
if ($stmt->num_rows >= "1") {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $src=$file_path.'/'.$row["key"];

     echo '<img class="myimg" src="'.$src.'" alt="There ya go" width="100" height="100" />';
   }
 }else{

   echo "0 records found";
}
 // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}




}


 ?>
```

I tried lot,read many more post  that seems to no mistake but can't point it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should add more error handling. Each and every method call may fail and your script should react to that situation.
E.g. there is no else-branch for

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT key FROM `database` WHERE value=?")) {
```

so, if prepare fails you'll never know. My suggestion is to (by default) first do the fail-branch.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT key FROM `database` WHERE value=?")
if (!$stmt) {
    someErrorHandlingHere();
}
else if ( !$stmt->bind_param("s", $image) ) {
    someErrorHandlingHere();
}
else if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
    someErrorHandlingHere();
}
else if ( !$stmt->bind_result($key) ) {
    someErrorHandlingHere();
}
else ...
```

I wonder how your "original" code could have worked since `key` is a reserved word/keyword in mysql, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: I know key is a reserved word,but in orginial it is kiti,i just wrote in quick,nevermind i modified it.But,even adding handlingerror nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->fetch();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

The first line already fetches one record from the result set.
If your query returns only one record then there's nothing left for the while-loop to fetch -> zero iterations.